"OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system:" while converting a panda dataframe to a .csv file on MacOS Ventura
I have a python code (running on terminal) where I am converting a Dataframe to a .csv file by the following code:
#Converting the dataframe to a csv file
relative_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
df.to_csv(relative_path+"/"+args.cleaned, index=False)

where args.cleaned is defined in the upper portion of the code as follows:
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run data cleaning.")
parser.add_argument('--cleaned', type=str, default='final.csv', help='Cleaned csv output')

While doing this I'm getting the following error:
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/final.csv'

I've searched this error on Google and stackOverflow and tried several things like giving read/write permission to the working directory using chmod. The most relevant source I got was this stackOverflow link. But it concerns a directory and many solutions do not apply to a file like I'm using a .csv file.
Important note: This code ran successfully for many months in the same working directory of the same device, and I never had a problem regarding this. Recently I had to reinstall Anaconda and Python, and just after that, I'm having this issue.
I have gone through almost all StackOverflow posts related to this error but didn't find the solution, specifically for a .csv file in Python.
Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Looks like you are trying to write to /final.csv in the root directory which is write protected for regular user.
Print your relative_path and relative_path+"/"+args.cleaned and take a look.

@YuriGinsburg Thanks Yuri! I did as you suggested and surprisingly the __file__ is printing the right value but the relative_path is empty!! I solved it using os.path.realpath().

I found a solution. Thanks to @Yuri for the comment because I could not think anything could be wrong with the relative_path as this same code was working fine before as I mentioned in my question.
So I printed both __file__ and relative_path for debugging purpose. Surprisingly the __file__ is printing the correct value but the relative_path is empty!! That is, somehow,  os.path.dirname(__file__) is returning an empty string! It was completely unexpected to me because I have used this same code in the same location with the same IDE(PyCharm) and never had an issue with this line of code.
Anyway, then I tried the absolute path to ensure that I get the absolute path of the script file, regardless of how it is executed. The following line of code solved the error:
script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
df.to_csv(script_path+"/"+args.cleaned, index=False)

